# How are Azure cognitive services updated?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services

new to Azure had some questions regarding Cognitive services.

1. How are Azure cognitive services updated?
2. Do we get new versions?
3. Does it even need updating or Microsoft updates at their end considering we are just using API end points?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a cloud based solution. Improvents or updates are done by Microsoft. The only thing that might need updating are SDKs (see [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/#additional-resources)) you might be using or REST api calls if they have changed or have been updated.

But unless there are breaking changes in the REST api you don't need to worry about having to update things. You might need to update the code if newer possibilities are presented and you want to use them.

One of the reason of using a managed cloud service like Azure Cognitive Services is that you don't need to worry about infrastructure and updates.